# Excluding items if they have values during a particular time period

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause, having-clause

I'm trying to return a list of accounts that are selling a particular product (SourceCustomerProductCode = 102) and want to see accounts that have sold this product in year 2013, but if they sold it in 2012, they I want them excluded from my query (i.e. I only want to return NEW customers).  My below query is returning accounts that sold this product in 2013, but includes accounts that sold it in 2012.

I know I can write this under the SELECT area using a case when for the [CaseAndGalloneVolume] statement, but need to write this statement in the where clause, because eventually I am going to add other products to my table.

Thanks for any help!

```
SELECT 

sum([FactActualDetail].[CaseAndGallonVolume]) AS [CaseAndGallonVolume],
sum([FactActualDetail].[AdjGrossMarginAmount]) AS [AdjGrossMarginAmount],
left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7) as [Acct #]

FROM [dbo].[FactActualDetail] [FactActualDetail] 

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DimCustomer] [DimCustomer] ON ([FactActualDetail].[CustomerSK] [DimCustomer].[CustomerSK])
LEFT JOIN [Common].[DimDate] [DimDate] ON ([FactActualDetail].[DeliveryDateSK] = [DimDate].[DateSK])

WHERE [Fiscal_Year] = 2013 AND [EQMultiplier] > 0 AND ([SuperChannelCode] = 04 OR [SuperChannelCode] = 06 OR [SuperChannelCode] = 07) AND (substring([SourceCustomerProductCode],8,3) = 102) 

GROUP BY left([FactActualDetail].[SourceCustomerProductCode],7)
```

Comment: Amik's answer works, but then if I add [Fiscal_Month] or [Fiscal_Year] (which comes from another table DimDate) under SELECT, his answer doesn't work.  It thens pulls accts with Volume from past years.

Comment: Because you need add WHERE [Fiscal_Year] IN (2013, 2012) and then check condition HAVING MIN([Fiscal_Year]) = 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try placing

```
HAVING MIN([Fiscal_Year]) = 2013
```

at the end of the query.

Comment: Yes that works. I did have to remove the Fiscal_Year in my Where clause to get that to work.  Not to make things more tricky, but if I wanted to add another product to my SQL, let's say product 111, but I wanted to include their volume for 2012, as well as 2013, I would need a subquery?

Comment: not sure what you mean. the HAVING clause is processed after GROUP BY and tosses all grouped rows with some product in year 2012, so only clients with all products in 2013 (none in 2012) will be displayed. If you assign somebody a product in 2012, yes, he will not be returned by this query, you have to make another workaround (at first place make clear how to define clients you want to return by the query)

Comment: @Dale: If this additional question is vital to choosing the right method of filtering the data, you should probably add it to your main post.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new aggregation column:

```
sum(case when year = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) as invalidItemCount
```

and filter on it:

```
having invalidItemCount = 0
```

This works for arbitrary filter expressions, not just for just the year 2013.